# how to add address of input file when creating jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans, exe

I have created a project in java Netbeans and I want to create an .exe or .jar file that can be run on any other systems. 
my project have a Main.java class and an other class GetRules.java .
the .exe file should be such that it can be run in any folder that contain train.txt as input and create Model.txt as output

how can I do this?

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is an executable file which can execute you project
calling you main class

so here is what you can do

step 1 : collect all the files , class files

step 2 : create a jar file collecting all the files from your project

step 3 : this.jar file is executable on any environment with a JVM available

you will have  .jar file , rather than .exe file , but serves you the purpose

you can refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/) link to learn how to create jar files

Comment: @RezanMoradi : well in that case , just refer the ans of the question , which is marked the duplicate question for you , just visit thatanswer

Comment: how can I specify the address of input file such that be independent of my system?

Comment: have you gone through the turorial ? , it uses address from onwards your package structure , you dont need to mention the complete path

Answer (score 0):

Java programs are not compiled into `exe` files but Java byte code which is usually stored in `jar` containers. `exe` files run on Windows systems only, but Java byte code is platform independent.

What you could do is use a wrapper like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html). It wraps the jar file into an exe file.